# SQL Adding Function

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a function that adds values that are selected from two different tables. I need the `SUM` of one column for a specific id in table 1, added to the `SUM` of a column for a specific id in table 2.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSum(@id varchar(9)) --Our IDs are strings of length 9
RETURNS integer --I've also tried decimal(x,x) and int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @total as integer; -- same here with decimal and int
SELECT @total = 
(
    (select SUM(Amount)
    from table1
    where id = @id)
    +
    (select SUM(amount)
    from table2
    where id = @id)
);
RETURN @total;
END;
```

I get several types of errors when I try to create this function, like `incorrect syntax near 'integer'`, `Must declare the scalar variable "@total".`, and `Incorrect syntax near 'END'.`

I've tried several variations and looked at several SO questions, but haven't found one that's fixed this issue for me yet. This is on SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried declaring two different variables, storing the sum of each table into each variable and then performing an addition on them?

Comment: Yes, and that also didn't work, with similar errors to what I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned the cause of your error is you did not define a datatype for your inbound parameter.

I would suggest a bit of a departure from the current structure. Instead of a scalar function I would use an inline table valued function. Something along these lines.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSum(@id int)
RETURNS table
AS RETURN

SELECT SUM(MyAmount)
from
(
    select SUM(Amount) as MyAmount
    from table1
    where id = @id
    UNION ALL
    select SUM(amount)
    from table2
    where id = @id

) x;
```

Comment: There were multiple errors, even after declaring the parameter type, but your suggestion with the `UNION ALL` is perfect, and goes right along with what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: So, I did have to make a minor edit from what you returned. The `UNION ALL` part of the function works fine, but I just had to return the whole thing as a table, without the outer `select SUM(MyAmount) from` part. It returns a table with one column, MyAmount, and then I can add those together.

Comment: Cool. Glad you were able to at least get a solid solution from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the parameter type in the function definiton

Try with the following

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSum(@id int)
RETURNS integer --I've also tried decimal(x,x)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @total as integer; -- same here with decimal
SELECT @total = 
(
    (select SUM(Amount)
    from table1
    where id = @id)
    +
    (select SUM(amount)
    from table2
    where id = @id)
);
RETURN @total;
END;
```

Comment: I've updated my original question. I did forget the parameter type originally, but have added it and still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare the type of the parameter

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSum(@id int)
```

Comment: I noticed I hadn't done that after, but it still is causing issues. I'm not sure why, I've done the same thing on other functions and not getting that error.

Comment: I can create the function in my db if I add the datatype

Comment: what SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I think 2014. I'd have to check, but I'm pretty sure it's 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Your data types should be INT and there are general syntax errors... see below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSum(@id AS INT) -- Declare your paramater AS (datatype)
RETURNS INT  -- No need for AS here, just start your block
BEGIN
DECLARE @total AS INT; 
SELECT @total = 
(
    (select SUM(Amount)
    from TableOne
    where id = @id)
    +
    (select SUM(amount)
    from TableTwo
    where id = @id)
);
RETURN @total;
END;
```